# onSubmit without a form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, facebook-graph-api

So I have a textfield (

```
<input type="text"/>
```

) where I want to run a function when the user presses enter/submits it.

Now, onSubmit looks like the best solution. Sadly this requires a form (as far as I know), and that form reloads the page when I submit. And it adds some extra code which I don't like. 
I've also tried the onKeyPress, but this reacts to every time the user types something in (see my previous question). I've tried looking for the 'enter'-key in the function itself, but that didn't work to well. And I don't want to run the function every time someone types something in the field.

So, to sum it up: I want to run a function when a user submits a textfield. How do I do this? Is there a way where I can use the 'onSubmit' function without using a form? 
What do pages like Facebook do when I comment on something?

I'm actually trying to make a Facebook comment function. This is the code I have so far:

```
var facebook_footer = '<button onClick="fbLike(\''+post_id+'\')"> Like </button> <form onSubmit="fbComment(\''+post_id+'\')"><input type="text" id="' + post_id + '" /></form>';

function fbComment(post_id) {
  var message = document.getElementById(post_id).value;
  console.log('Trying to comment on: ' + post_id);

  FB.api('/'+ post_id +'/comments?message=' + message, 'post', function(response) {
    if (!response || response.error) {
      alert('Error occured. ID: ' + post_id);
    } else {
      alert('Great! It worked. ID: ' + post_id);
    }
  });
}
```

Maybe you have some knowledge on the FBapi, and know what's standard procedure here?

Anyway, thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: 1. Forms do not require the page to reload (if OnSubmit is returned FALSE)
2. You do not NEED a submit, you could us an <input type="button" onclick="function();">
3. If you want to use form elements without using a form, I'd suggest document.getElementById("NAME") to figure out your different inputs.

Comment: 1. Okay, so I tried using a form at first. What happened was that the function didn't even have the time to run. The page just reloaded when I pressed enter and added a '?' after the url. 2. I do not want a button, I just want the user to press enter. 3. I'm using document.getElementById('id') to get the content of the textfield. But the problem is running the function when the user presses 'enter'.

Comment: The enter key is ASCII 13 so something like this should work: onkeypress="return myFuntion(event)" funtion myFunction(e){if (e.keyCode == 13) {return true;} else{ return false;}}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way would be to have that form, and use the `onSubmit`. To prevent the form from actually submitting on its own (and use your own JS function), just `return false` from that function.

Comment: How would I return false from the function? What happened when I tried using a form was that the page reloaded as soon as I pressed enter. The function didn't even have the time to run... And it added a '?' to the end of the URL. How do I prevent the form from updating the page?

Comment: either use a jQuery event handler, or simply create a function and call it from the `<form>` tag by putting a function call similar to `<form onsubmit="myFunction()">`. Then, in that function, simply `return false;` and the form won't submit at all.

Comment: I have included the function to run in my question. Where would I put the return false? If I look at the console, I can see that I get the: 'Trying to comment on: xxxxxx', but then the page reloads and the last bit (actually commenting) isn't run.

Comment: The topic of the question is "onSubmit WITHOUT a form". If you have a form it's easey: you can call `event.preventDefault()` in its `onsubmit`, or yes, `return false`. What if we actually REALLY DON"T HAVE that form and there is no way for it to be added?

Comment: @ZeusZdravkov The author clearly asked for a method to submit data in an non-obtrusive way. Not wanting a form was due to it refreshing the screen, which in my answer I show to be a non-issue (and do note -- this was in 2013, a LOT has changed since). If you can run JS, you can create a form. If you do not want a form, simply use the `onClick` of a button or similar element that triggers the data being sent.

Comment: @NickAndriopoulos Yes, okay, in this private situation it addresses OP's quandary, however, Stack Overflow is made to help more than one individual. When you search on Google "onSubmit without a form" you get to this answer, which does not address your search (where you said WITHOUT), neither the title of the question, however.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the application, onBlur or onChange. onChange fires when the value of the field changes. onBlur fires when the field loses focus, regardless of value.

Comment: The change event is dispatched **when the control loses focus** and the value has changed (except for radio buttons and checkboxes in some browsers).

Comment: I don't know how this would work... Because I have a textfield, and I want a function to run when the user 'submits' it/ presses enter.

Comment: *"onChange fires when the value of the field changes"* - No, see @RobG 's comment. Use onInput instead.